# TextLabel and UITextField as accessoryview are overlaping each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview cell in which I am adding a textfield as accessory view, but textlabel and the textfield in accessory view are overlaping each other as shown in the image. Strangest thing is that if I set the background color of the cell, it shows it over the whole cell but when I check its frame, It shows a width of 240.0. What am I missing here?
[image: Cell Snapshot]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
SettingCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[SettingCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.accessoryView = nil;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

cell.textLabel.text = nil;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;

cell.textLabel.text = @"Facebook default message with image";
       UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 30)];
        cell.accessoryView = textField;
        textField.delegate = self;


        textField.text = facebookDefaultMessageForImage;
        textField.placeholder = @"Default message";
        textField.tag = 1;
        [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: May I ask what is the downvote for?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing constraints, please take a look how to work with constraints.

Comment: I set constraints for textLabel and its working fine but everytime i set those for accessoryView, the app crashes.

Comment: @ZeeshanAnjum If you can edit your answer with constraint code as well, then I can say what is wrong. Right now you describing constraint problem with a code that doesn't include constraints. If you did it from storyboard, please add screenshots.